# Setting title tag's string attribute clears string attribute of another tag in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I try to change title tags of some html documents using BeautifulSoup with the following code:

```
>>> doc = BeautifulSoup(open(filename))
>>> root = doc.find('html') # works only with html parser
>>> hafta = root.find(id="hafta")
>>> content = hafta.find('div', {'class':'convHtml'})
>>> content.find('b').string
u'BAKANLARA N\u0130\xc7\u0130N KURBAN KES\u0130L\u0130R?'
>>> doc.title.string = content.find('b').string
>>> content.find('b').string
>>>
```

Oddly, the statement `doc.title.string = content.find('b').string` clears the string inside `content.find('b')`. Why does this occur?

Comment: Can you post the HTML source document referenced by `filename` somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [a bug in Beautiful Soup](https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/983050). I've committed a fix which will be released in the next version.

Comment: Good to know that it's goint to be fixed soon :)